# Raycast returns null for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, so quick question, I made a simple:

```
Ray ray;
```

Then in the update() I made a simple:

```
ray = Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Debug.Log(Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));
```

And for some reason, in the console, the debug.log registers a ray being casted while ray just thinks it's null.

Any ideas?

This is the debug.log output:

> Origin: (-0.2, 2.5, 14.8), Dir: (-0.4, 0.5, -0.7)
>   Unity.engine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   TankController:Update() (at Assets/Games/Chisana/Scripts/TankController.cs:136)

This is the ray output:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   TankController.Update() (at Assets/Games/Chisana/Scripts/TankController.cs:135)

In case I overlooked something, here's the full script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TankController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 targetPosition;
    Vector3 lookAtTarget;

    public Vector4 selectedColor;
    public Vector4 deselectedColor;

    Quaternion playerRot;

    public float rotSpeed = 2;
    public float speed = 3;

    bool OneExecution = false;
    int count = 0;

    public bool Moving = false;
    public bool Selected = false;
    public bool UiSelected = false;
    public bool Hovering = false;

    public GameObject UI;
    public BoxCollider HitBox;

    public DoEverything Properties;
    public GameObject childObj;

    public MeshRenderer mrHighlight;

    public PlayerMaster playerMaster;
    int playerMasterTeam;

    SkinnedMeshRenderer[] skinnedMeshRenderersScan;
    public List<SkinnedMeshRenderer> skinnedMeshRenderersList = new List<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();

    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;

    void Start()
    {
        Properties = GetComponentInChildren<DoEverything>(); //Get the DoEverything script

        childObj = Properties.InstancedEntity; //Get the object it will spawn

        if (mrHighlight.enabled != false && mrHighlight != null) //Make sure the highlight isn't enabled and not null
        {
            mrHighlight.enabled = false;
        }

        skinnedMeshRenderersScan = childObj.GetComponentsInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>(); //Looks for all skinned mesh renderers in child object

        foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer element in skinnedMeshRenderersScan) //For every object it finds
        {
            if (!skinnedMeshRenderersList.Contains(element)) //If it isn't already in this list
            {
                skinnedMeshRenderersList.Add(element); //Add to the list
            }
        }

        playerMasterTeam = playerMaster.Team;
    }

    void LClickRay()
    {

    }

    void RClickRay()
    {

    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        Hovering = true;
        foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer element in skinnedMeshRenderersScan) //For every object it finds
        {
            element.material.color = selectedColor;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        Hovering = false;
        foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer element in skinnedMeshRenderersScan) //For every object it finds
        {
            element.material.color = deselectedColor;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Physics.IgnoreCollision(collision.collider, HitBox);
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,
                                                    playerRot,
                                                    rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                                targetPosition,
                                                speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position == targetPosition)
        {
            Moving = false;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            LClickRay();
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            RClickRay();
        }

        if (Moving == true)
        {
            Move();
        }

        ray = Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.Log(Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));
    }
}
```

Comment: ray = Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

Comment: Well, yes the Debug and ray are separate lines of code. The only difference is that debug is calling it and showing what it is in the console. While ray is calling it and storing it in a Ray variable called ray.

Comment: The trouble is that when debug calls it, it detects it no problem. When I try to store it in a variable, it just pretends like it's null.

Comment: Please don't add output as images but rather as raw text and format it as output (prefix `> `)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use `Camera.current`!**

From the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-current.html)

> The camera we are currently **rendering** with, **for low-level render control only** (Read Only).
>
> Most of the time you will want to use [Camera.main](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) instead. Use this function **only** when implementing one of the following events: [MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html), [MonoBehaviour.OnPreRender](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPreRender.html), [MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html).

---

So instead use [Camera.main](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)

> The first enabled camera tagged "MainCamera" (Read Only).

Also note

> The primary Camera in the Scene. Returns null if there is no such camera in the Scene. This property uses `FindGameObjectsWithTag` internally and doesn't cache the result. It is advised to cache the return value of Camera.main if it is used multiple times per frame.

So make sure the  camera is tagged `MainScene`, aktive and than you should use this also only once to get the reference and re-use it like

```
private Camera _mainCamera;

private void Awake ()
{
    _mainCamera = Camera.main;

    //Maybe a check
    if(!_mainCamera)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No MainCamera in Scene!");
        enabled = false;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    // ...

    ray = _mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Debug.Log(ray);
}
```

Comment: I just changed current to main and it worked just fine but, if it isn't too much trouble, would you happen to know how you'd do this for a multiplayer situation?

Comment: what do you mean? In a "multiplayer situation" there still should only be one aktive MainCamera, right? Or do you mean a shared screen?

Comment: Like, each player should have their own perspective.

Comment: My question was: Is it a shared screen? Do you want to display both camera perspectives on the same device?

Comment: No, it will be online multiplayer.

Comment: ... than where is the problem? there will/should be only one `MainCamera` in the scene anyway, right?

Comment: So then each player object in the scene can have a MainCamera that they can use to cast rays and such?

Comment: yes they should .. you just have to make sure as usual to disable the camera on the other player object which is not `IsLocalPlayer` or simply in general only have one MainCamera in your scene ... your players don't have to spawn one at all